# How to increase the waiting time on networkidle in playwright?

Tags: playwright

The default  wait time for networkidle to fire in PlayWright is 500 milliseconds - is it possible to increase that?  I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find a way to do that.

Comment: Just use page.waitFor("enter your time here",etc.)

Comment: I was trying to get it to be more universal

Comment: Networkidle is quite flaky. Please don't rely on it in your tests.

Comment: @Be-WiseIndependent that's deprecated, and also totally different than networkidle, which waits 500 ms once the network becomes idle (no live requests on the air).

Comment: @SteveFrench why do you need this? There's probably a [better way to achieve whatever you need this for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876) if you don't mind providing context. The 500 ms delay is basically a race condition, so extending that to 1 or 2 seconds means you're probably relying too heavily on an arbitrary value that might slow your tests down and/or give false positives rather than a specific `waitForResponse`, `waitForFunction`, locator, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You don't need to , thanks to [auto-wait](https://playwright.dev/docs/actionability) feature in playwright.

- 

> Playwright performs a range of actionability checks on the elements
> before making actions to ensure these actions behave as expected. It
> auto-waits for all the relevant checks to pass and only then performs
> the requested action. If the required checks do not pass within the
> given timeout, action fails with the TimeoutError.

- 

Note: Networkidle is quite [flaky](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/2515#issuecomment-724163391) - any analytics script can mess it up. Please don't rely on it in your tests.

Navigating to a URL auto-waits for the page to fire the load event. If the page does a client-side redirect before load, page.goto() will auto-wait for the redirected page to fire the load event.

```
// Navigate the page
await page.goto('https://example.com');
```

#### Wait for element

In lazy-loaded pages, it can be useful to wait until an element is visible with locator.waitFor(). Alternatively, page interactions like page.click() auto-wait for elements.

```
// Navigate and wait for element
await page.goto('https://example.com');
await page.getByText('Example Domain').waitFor();

// Navigate and click element
// Click will auto-wait for the element
await page.goto('https://example.com');
await page.getByText('Example Domain').click();
```

Source: [https://playwright.dev/docs/navigations#:~:text=Auto%2Dwait%E2%80%8B,to%20fire%20the%20load%20event](https://playwright.dev/docs/navigations#:%7E:text=Auto%2Dwait%E2%80%8B,to%20fire%20the%20load%20event).

Comment: I assumed that network idle worked better than it does - waitfor has solved everything.  Thank you!